# How is it called if "$f(g(x_0), g(x_1), ...) = g(f(x_0,x_1,...))$"

Tags: functions

What is the correct mathematic term to be used for the relation between two functions $f$ and $g$ if the following holds:
$$f\big(g(x_0), g(x_1), ...\big) = g\big(f(x_0,x_1,...)\big)$$
Thanks.

Comment: Generalized commutativity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that is an identity, this is the same as saying $f\circ g=g\circ f$, which is to say these two functions commute (under function composition, if you like).

Comment: To be picky, we have $f \circ (g \times g \times \cdots) = g \circ f$.